# How to make simple path with alias in .bash_profile (Mac)

Tags: macos, path, alias, ogre, bash

I'm setting alias in .bash_profile in mac, like below:

> alias XMLtoMESH='/OgreSDK/OgreCommandLineToolsMac_1.8.0/OgreXMLConverter'
>
> alias OgreSource='~/garage-project/tryCV/tryOgre/tryOgre/media/Export/'

Actually, OgreXMLConverter is Command line tool, but I just want rename it with my own (XMLtoMESH), and it's work with no problem and issues when file start to execute. But little bit issue come from the path, because I must put "long" path like this **"~/garage-project/tryCV/tryOgre/tryOgre/media/Export/"** to convert my native file. So, the problem is, how I make it simple, because I try to add in .bash_profile with alias, it's doesn't work properly.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need alias for path. You can try this:

`OgreSource="$(echo $HOME)/garage-project/tryCV/tryOgre/tryOgre/media/Export/"`

and use it like this:

`cd ${OgreSource}`